# Know when network connectivity returns

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application that tries to be a good samaritan, basically, when any services start that needs to interact with the network.  I am checking to see if the device has connectivity:

**hasConnectivity Method**

```
private boolean hasConnectivity() {
    NetworkInfo info = mConnectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean connected = false;
    int netType = -1; 
    int netSubtype = -1; 

    if (info == null) {
        Log.w(sTag, "network info is null");
        notifyUser(MyIntent.ACTION_VIEW_ALL, "There is no network connectivity.", false);
    } else if (!mConnectivity.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
        Log.w(sTag, "background data setting is not enabled");
        notifyUser(MyIntent.ACTION_VIEW_ALL, "background data setting is disabled", false);
    } else {
        netType = info.getType();
        netSubtype = info.getSubtype();

        if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            connected = info.isConnected();
        } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
                   && netSubtype == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
                   && !mTelephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()
                  ) { 
            connected = info.isConnected();
        } else if (info.isRoaming()) {
            notifyUser(MyIntent.ACTION_VIEW_ALL, "Currently Roaming skipping check.", false);
        } else if (info.isAvailable()) {
            connected = info.isConnected();
        } else {
            notifyUser(MyIntent.ACTION_VIEW_ALL, "..There is no network connectivity.", false);
        }   
    }   
    return connected;
}
```

When this method returns false I know that I don't have a connection because the user is on the phone or 3g and wifi is not available

What is the best way to know **when Connectivity is available without pulling the network stats with a timer periodically**?

Is there an **Intent** action that I can observe with a broadcast receiver that will announce a change with connectivity?

Thanks for any help, I will keep searching the docs for some clue on what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have for checking Internet-access (actually, more like if the Wifi is enabled and connected to a network).

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(action.equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION))
    {
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        MainMap.setWifiState(wm.getWifiState());
        Log.e("Debug", "Setting wifistate: " + wm.getWifiState());
    } else if(action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
    {
        NetworkInfo ni = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        MainMap.setConnected(ni.isConnected());
        Log.e("Debug", "Setting isConnected: " + ni.isConnected());
        if(ni.isConnected()) Toast.makeText(context, "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

It shouldn't be too hard to check if the user is on 3G or on Wifi.

Comment: Thanks, must have missed the ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION when I was browsing the docs.  Was exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: Good to know my hours of searching and cursing helped someone besides myself.